# CefSharp with WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp WPF control in my project with MVVM pattern. I have tried to show external URL inside Chromium browser. I have used LoadingStateChanged event to track the page load event inside the Chromium browser. I am getting the below error message while listening for LoadingStateChanged event. Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

**Error Message:**

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
> thread owns it.

**HomeControl.xaml:**

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Address="{Binding Address, Mode=OneWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LoadingStateChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LoadingStateChangedCmd, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

**HomeViewModel.cs:**

```
public ICommand LoadingStateChangedCmd { get; set; }

public HomeViewModel() 
{
    LoadingStateChangedCmd = new CommunityToolkitInput.RelayCommand<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs>(LoadingStateChanged);
}

public void LoadingStateChanged(LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsLoading == false)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
        });
    }
}
```

**Detailed Error Message:**

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
> calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread
> owns it.   Source=WindowsBase   StackTrace:    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()    at
> System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)    at
> System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.get_Actions()    at
> System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object
> parameter)    at
> System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(EventArgs
> eventArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(Object
> sender, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
> CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.CefSharp.Internals.IWebBrowserInternal.SetLoadingStateChange(LoadingStateChangedEventArgs
> args)    at
> CefSharp.Internals.ClientAdapter.OnLoadingStateChange(ClientAdapter* ,
> scoped_refptr* browser, Boolean isLoading, Boolean
> canGoBack, Boolean canGoForward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it that way, because the event is triggered on a worker thread and the Interaction framework calls dependency properties in response to it which aren't callable from another non-GUI thread.

Handle the event in your view manually and do what needs to be done directly, even if it's just invoking a command in your VM.

Comment: Also unrelated, but you should be using `WebView2` instead, which is made to render directly in the XAML window stack. Unlike the CefBrowser which renders, as far as I know, more like a XAML island, covering controls it should be under instead and having big performance implications.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Let me try with the WebView2.

Comment: To be clear, they behave identically in this regard. The benefit of `WebView2` is that it's a fully supported WPF (and UWP and WinForms and WinUI 2 & 3) control, rather than a community provided one.

Comment: If I put callback events i.e., LoadingStateChanged in view's code behind c# file, it is violating MVVM design. Is my understanding correct? Is there any better approach available other than this?

Comment: It's not violating MVVM as long as the code in the view is view code, like opening a save dialog when you press the `Browse` button next to a text field to fill it in, or to do glue code like this.

Comment: `WebView2` at time of writing only provides a `HwndHost` based `WPF` implementation `CefSharp` provides two implementations `CefSharp.Wpf` a native `WPF` control, it does this by rendering every frame as a bitmap and forwarding events to the browser, this does have a performance impact. Three's also `CefSharp.Wpf.HwndHost` which is also a `HwndHost`. implementation `HwndHost` based implementations will have `AirSpace` issues, you cannot overlay other controls, perform transforms, etc. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation#hwnds-inside-wp

Comment: The `CefSharp.Wpf` implementation has no relation to `XAML Islands`. It will participate in `WPF` rendering just as any normal `WPF` control would. `HwndHost` implementations won't correctly participate in `WPF` rendering (refer `AirSpace` issues).  See also https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/286

Answer (score 1):

`LoadingStateChanged` event is by default called on the `CEF UI Thread` which by default is different to your `WPF UI Thread`. See [MultiThreadedMessageLoop](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#multithreadedmessageloop) for additional details on the subject. You can integrate `CEF` into your applications existing message loop, though generally in `WPF` this is unnecessary.

As alternatives to your current code there are a number of options.

**Option #1**
The `LoadingStateChangedEventArgs` event has three properties, for `MVVM` usage they are mapped to three `DependencyProperties` which you can bind to your `ViewModel`.

- [IsLoading](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/112.2.x/html/F_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_IsLoadingProperty.htm)
- [CanGoForward](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/112.2.x/html/F_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_CanGoForwardProperty.htm)
- [CanGoBack](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/112.2.x/html/F_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_CanGoBackProperty.htm)

**Option #2** You can access the `WebBrowser` in your view model.

```cs
// ViewModel property
private IWpfWebBrowser webBrowser;
public IWpfWebBrowser WebBrowser
{
    get { return webBrowser; }
    set { Set(ref webBrowser, value); }
}
```

```xml
<!-- XAML bind the WebBrowser property to your ViewModel -->
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

You can then `subscribe/unsubscribe` to the browser events you require.

**Option #3** You can subscribe to `LoadingStateChanged` event in `View` codebind and manually invoke the `ViewModel` command.